# Console App, C# Receipt Program

Tags: c#

I'm new in c# and I'm trying to print a receipt, but my code is not working. Here is my problem:

- Compute the Price multiplied by the quantity given by the user
- Compute the said Amount - 12% tax Show the Vat Tax Accept money and
- compute the change   they have to all appear once the unit price has been inputted

This is my code at the moment for the computation part

```
bool test = false;
do
{
    try
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(2, 12);
        Console.Write(" ");

        Console.SetCursorPosition(2, 12);
        Num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        test = false;
    }
    catch
    {
        test = true;
    }
} while (test);

Console.SetCursorPosition(18, 12);
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
telNumber = Console.ReadLine();

//Peso

bool Ptest = false;
do
{
    try
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(47, 12);
        Console.Write(" ");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(47, 12);
        Amount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.SetCursorPosition(65, 12);
        Amount = Amount * 2 ;

        Console.WriteLine("P " + Amount.ToString("0.00"));

        Console.SetCursorPosition(65, 15);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine("P " + Amount.ToString("0.00"));

        Console.SetCursorPosition(65, 17);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine("P " + Amount.ToString("0.00"));

        Ptest = false;
    }
    catch
    {
       Ptest = true;
    }
} while (Ptest);

//Amount

Console.ReadLine();
```

It has to look like this, Ive done the format but I'm having trouble with the said problems above, please help

[Program Image](http://static.tumblr.com/xklso8y/PUfng8s5h/clipboard01.png)

Comment: So what exactly isn't working?  You've stated what you want your program to do, but don't state which bit is causing you trouble.

Comment: I cant do the computations sir, my code accepts integer only but i cant compute the tax and the total amount. Please see the image, provided, i cant seem to get that right, the computations, that's the right program

Comment: You will never get a decimal value using an integer, try using the Decimal type instead.

Comment: Decimal is the recommended type to use when dealing with money in C#

Comment: Should i redo the codes and declare decimal value? but how can i declare a value being given by the user

Comment: If you want decimal values.. yes. you can use a method such as [Decimal.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557(v=vs.110).aspx) to validate that the value input is a valid number.

Answer (score 0):

Use decimal instad of integer 32.

```
       bool test = false;
        do
        {
            try
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(2, 12);
                Console.Write(" ");

                Console.SetCursorPosition(2, 12);
                Num = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
                test = false;
            }
            catch
            {
                test = true;
            }
        } while (test);

        Console.SetCursorPosition(18, 12);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        telNumber = Console.ReadLine();

        bool Ptest = false;
        do
        {
            try
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(47, 12);
                Console.Write(" ");
                Console.SetCursorPosition(47, 12);
                Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.SetCursorPosition(65, 12);
                Amount = Amount * 2;

                Console.WriteLine("P " + Amount.ToString("0.00"));

                Console.SetCursorPosition(65, 15);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("P " + Amount.ToString("0.00"));

                Console.SetCursorPosition(65, 17);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("P " + Amount.ToString("0.00"));

                Ptest = false;
            }
            catch
            {
                Ptest = true;
            }
        } while (Ptest);

        //Amount

        Console.ReadLine();
```